# rpi3, directly connected monitor, cant connect to $DISPLAY in code

Tags: python, numpy, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, vispy

Trying to display UI, mainy realtime data graphics and statistics on a screen directly connected to rpi3.

Using some example code from [Getting started with Vispy](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-06/)

been trying to display anything, but when running the example code i only get a warning message:

"WARNING: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display"

As far as i understand i have installed all the dependencies numpy, matlibplot, pyqt5 and others. Supposedly enabled opwnGL on rpi following the video [How to Enable OpenGL in Raspberry Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBefzN9WANY)
Cant understand the main problem. Firstly is it possible to use vispy on raspberry and are there any suggestions as to how do i connect to the display from my code?

example code:

```
import numpy as np
from vispy import app
from vispy import gloo
c = app.Canvas(keys='interactive')
vertex = """
attribute vec2 a_position;
void main (void)
{
     gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
"""
```

Also tried an example from [Matplotlib Animation Tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)

But this also end in an error : "_thinker.TclError: coulnt connect to display"

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
// First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
// initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
return line,
// animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
// call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: just want to leave an update:
solved it by updating pyqt5 installation with easy_install. previously installed version (by sudo apt-get install python3.pyqt5) did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to leave an update: solved it by updating pyqt5 installation with easy_install. previously installed version (by sudo apt-get install python3.pyqt5) did not work